# Concise rule on when to use `run()` in RethinkDb javascript driver

Tags: rethinkdb

Sometimes `run()` does not need to be appended after a query.

e.g:

`r.table('someTable').getAll()` is identical (?) to `r.table('someTable').getAll().run()`

Any concise rule on when to use or omit `run`, or can I always use run for consistency's sake even though sometimes it's redundant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`run` should always be necessary in the JS driver, and never in the Data Explorer.  In the JS driver, `r.table(...).getAll()` should return a query object rather than actually running the query.

Comment: Perhaps it's because I'm using promises and chaining with `then`, which presumably auto-fills the `run` if forgotten or something..

Comment: Ah, that's possible.